# OSERROR: Protocol Not Found

Tags: python-3.x, flask-socketio

I am trying to built a python chat app but while running it I got an error...

```
"/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dns/rdtypes/IN/WKS.py", line 25, in <module>
    _proto_tcp = socket.getprotobyname('tcp')
OSError: protocol not found

[Program finished]
```

The python program:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Please help me if you got the fix...

Comment: [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40185488/2052575) appears to work for debian/ubuntu based systems.  Looks like you're running in Pydroid IDE though, so not sure if that will help.